# ASP.NET System.Web.Abstractions why were they created as an abstract Base class?

Tags: asp.net, interface, abstract, system.web.abstractions

As above really, I'm wondering why Microsoft released the abstractions as abstract classes instead of interfaces?

I would be interested in any insights because I need to do something similar for standard things like System.IO features for File and Directory, however I feel that an interface would feel nicer?

There must be a good reason why an abstract was chosen instead, other than the fact it fits into their assembly namespace better, System.Web.ABSTRACTions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Phil (Haack, from the ASP.NET MVC team) explained this decision on his blog. Check out this post:

[Versioning Issues With Abstract Base Classes and Interfaces](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/02/21/versioning-issues-with-abstract-base-classes-and-interfaces.aspx)